# Trip computer reported MPG with engine remap or chip

Tags: fuel-consumption, fuel-injection, computer

A question related to [Car average mpg display correctness](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6496/car-average-mpg-display-correctness) I suppose, but say if a piggy back chip (e.g. http://www.dieselandpetroltuning.co.uk/) was added to a diesel car with trip computer, would the trip computer take into account the extra fuel injected via the remap/chip, or would the increase in fuel consumption be ignored and make the trip computer less accurate?

Sites selling chips such as these claim

> Improved MPG for high mileage drivers

but to test these claims, would you have to measure the relative consumption manually rather than use the relative values reported by the trip computer before and after fitting?

Comment: Can you provide more application-specific information? My first thought would be that a chip shouldn't interfere with the trip computer's ability to read how long the injectors are open for--which is how the fuel consumption is typically calculated.

Comment: @mac The answer to the linked question suggests that the amount of fuel to be sprayed is calculated, but the trip computer uses the intended amount rather than the actual amount. If the chip causes more fuel to be sprayed, does the trip computer still believe that only the intended amount was sprayed, not the amount overridden by the chip?

Comment: The question I was driving at (and what I believe you'd need more information on the specific chip to determine) is whether the factory ECU sees the actual injector opening times, or whether the "piggyback chip" comes in downstream and asks for more fuel without the factory ECU knowing. Answer this question, and you've answered your question. I've done performance chips on two of my vehicles, (one re-flash, one solder-in), and in those cases, the chip played nice with the factory ECU such that the true, "chipped" operating state was known to the factory ECU.

Answer (score 2):

Great question. I am making an educated guess here, so don't quote me in court;)

Because piggyback chips interfere with your car's various inputs I would assume that you are correct and that your MPG score will be inaccurate as a result. I can't say by how much though. These chips usually give an MPG boost of around 10%, so I would imagine your true MPG would be 10% less than your trip computer says it is. Not that it was 100% accurate to begin with. Toyota engines have an AIr/Fuel ratio sensor that is much more accurate than the usual Oxygen sensors found in most other engines, so you're probably coming of an inaccurate base to begin with.

If it makes you feel any better, my Opel reports my fuel consumption to be 10% less than it actually is, so if I were in your shoes, it'd probably improve the accuracy;)

Comment: ...and you can always test it before and after at the gas station to see if the chip improves your mileage instead of relying on the computer.

Comment: Any reference regarding your statement about how only Toyota engines measure the fuel volume passing through the injectors? This doesn't sound correct to me.

Comment: Sure. I came across this while developing an OBD app for my car. Toyota has an Air/Fuel ratio sensor, while most other cars have an Oxygen sensor: http://www.motor.com/article.asp?article_ID=1643. Although it seems I was wrong about the position and the exact function of the sensor.

Comment: There's also this PDF which discusses the advantages: http://www.autoshop101.com/forms/h37.pdf

Comment: Neither an air/fuel ratio sensor nor an oxygen sensor measure fuel consumption. Fuel consumption is measured at the injectors.

Comment: Actually not. It is arrived at by the formula MPG =VSS * 7.718/MAF, as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170646/fuel-consumption-from-obd2-port-parameters

Comment: See also http://www.sersc.org/journals/IJUNESST/vol4_no4/3.pdf

Comment: @JuannStrauss the research paper you cite seeks to find a vehicle-general method of estimating fuel consumption (when you don't know the fuel injector parameters), and in fact it states **"The fuel consumption data is supported by automotive company in real amount of fuel 
injection. This data has been used as a reference value to obtain an estimation model."** I.E. the injected fuel quantity is the standard by which they judged the accuracy of their estimate. Check out the relevant sections of the Bosch Automotive Handbook or Bosch Gasoline Engine Management--they're the guys who made the ECU

Comment: @mac, Yes, accurate fuel consumption is read from VSS and fuel injector pulse width data. That gives you all you need. The formula you mention early assumes a perfect 14.7 combustion, which is not always the case (richer during warmup and acceleration, leaner during decel and cruise).

Answer (score 0):

Like @mac said, it all depends on what the piggyback/chip does. If it modifies the signal to the injectors and the ECU does not see these changes, then your MPG-o-meter will be off.

However, if it is like a "reflash" where the ECU uses new values for it's load vs RPM fuel injection tables, then it should still be as accurate.